# Decoding with Qt an Image Encoded with Java ImageIO class

Tags: java, c++, qt, javax.imageio

I want to display an image using C++, more precisely using Qt Framework.
The image has been encoded using ImageIO.write method in this way:

```
          BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("c:\\image.jpg"));
          // convert BufferedImage to byte array
          ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          ImageIO.write(originalImage, "jpg", baos);
          baos.flush();
          imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
          baos.close();
```

Then the content of the ByteArrayOutputStream is simply dumped in a file image.out and this is the file I need to convert back to an Image but using C++.
I see that the size of the file image.jpg is greater than the size of the image.out file so the Java must make some compression or encoding that I don't know. So I can't just read the image as JPG and put it in a QImage or QPixmap object.

Does anyone know how the ImageIO class encodes an image ?

Comment: Did you try to just read it with Qt?

Comment: No I didn't. I just tried to open it with GIMP and the Windows image viewer and both fail. I think Qt expects an image in jpg format and not this type of encoding.

Comment: Why do you decode the image just to encode it again? Why not just open the image in Qt? Or do you plan to add image processing in Java as well? PS: Using `ImageIO.write(...)` will encode the image with format specific default settings. If you want more control, use the `ImageReader` and `ImageWriter` and specify quality settings, metadata etc.

Comment: According to the docs it's "jpeg", not "jpg". `getReaderFormatNames()` should return the list of supported formats. Also, check the return value of write().

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I've seen both `jpeg` and `jpg` used in official Oracle docs. I prefer `jpeg`, but both work, and are equivalent for the standard ImageIO JPEG plugin. Good point on checking the return value of `write()`!

Comment: I can't just open the image in Qt because the original image and the "encoded" one are on two different device. I only have access to the encoded image. I didn't handle the Java side but the guy that sent me the code snippet told me that the image is scaled before writing it to output file. That could be the cause of size difference among the two image. But although the image is scaled, accordingly to what you sad the output image must be in standard jpeg format. Am I correct ?

Comment: Some versions of the standard plugin has had issues I'm sure, but generally you should get a standard JPEG, yes. However, this is easier for you to test than it is for others (without access) to guess... If you can't test using QT, try other software. Also, as you talk about different devices, perhaps the data is corrupted in the transfer process?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how the ImageIO class encodes an image ?

The best choice is probably to read the [Java Image I/O API Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/imageio/spec/imageio_guideTOC.fm.html) from Oracle.

It describes the basics and the plugin mechanism used for writing. You want to read at least section 3 (and especially 3.4 about the `ImageWriter`), and maybe 4.1 for an introduction to the plugin concept.

For details on how to control JPEG format specific write settings, see [JPEGImageWriteParam](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/plugins/jpeg/JPEGImageWriteParam.html) API doc.

PS: Your code looks ok though, and should provide a valid JPEG, provided the ImageIO reader plugin can read your initial file (the `com.sun.imageio.plugins.JPEGImageReader` is very restrictive in regards to non-standard files, even if most other software happily reads them).

PPS: The standard ImageIO JPEG writer plugin (`com.sun.imageio.plugins.JPEGImageWriter`) uses the [Independent JPEG Group (IJG)](http://www.ijg.org/) JPEG library to write its JPEG stream. I don't think you can get much more "standard" than that.